# Trying to print the first element of a nested list using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have done my research on the web, even looked at solution for this particular problem from HackerRank but since it is supposed to be an exercise with list comprehension, I keep to it.

I keep getting `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x04246760>` for the following code:

```
mainList = []

for _ in range(int(input())):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())

mainList.append([name,score])

mainList.sort(key = lambda x: [x[1],x[0]])
mainList = list(filter(lambda x: x[1] != mainList[0][1], mainList))

print([y for y,z in x if z == mainList[0][1]] for x in mainList)
print(y for x in mainList for y,z in x if z == mainList[0][1])
```

Using debug in VSCode, the content of `mainList` is exactly what I am expecting but the print part errors out.
Both `print(...)` are my attempt.  I just need to know why they don't work.

Here is the input data:

```
5
Harry
37.21
Berry
37.21
Tina
37.2
Akriti
41
Harsh
39
```

Comment: It's not an error. If you don't put the generator inside `[]`, it's a generator, not a list comprehension. The generator doesn't return the elements until you iterate over it.

Comment: Just add `[]` around the argument in the last line.

Comment: print([[y for y,z in x if z == mainList[0][1]] for x in mainList])
    print([y for x in mainList for y,z in x if z == mainList[0][1]])        
Tried it on both print lines and now i get "Too many value to unpack (expected 2)". Something I am missing...

Comment: `mainList.append([name, score])` needs to be inside the `for` loop.

Comment: What is the result you're trying to get? It looks like the generators in the `print()` lines are doing the same thing as the `filter()` function.

Comment: Sorry...my mistake while I tranferred the code here...mainList.append([name, score]) is in the for loop.

Comment: What I want is to print the "name" element of each subList where the "score" element is equal to the "score" element of the of the first subList of the mainList (mainList[0][1])

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244519/discussion-between-jean-cedric-hamel-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

```
mainList = []

for _ in range(int(input())):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())

    mainList.append([name,score])

mainList.sort(key = lambda x: [x[1],x[0]])
mainList = list(filter(lambda x: x[1] != mainList[0][1], mainList))

print(*[x[0] for x in mainList if x[1] == mainList[0][1]], sep = "\n")
```

Many thanks to Barmar